# Is it possible to specify language for share link dialog for facebook?

Tags: html, facebook

I have created a share to Facebook link that when clicked , a new tab opens, with sharing dialog. However it's always in English regardless of local SDK I have declared. Is it possible to make the dialog page on Facebook changing it's language according the SDK locals(maybe with a var in the url)?

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=87741124305&href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fattribution_link%3Fa%3DhGJm3k84Eas%26u%3D%252Fwatch%253Fv%253DsNZwF483W8U%2526feature%253Dshare&display=popup&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com" target="_blank">share</a>
```

Comment: Well of course this does not take into account what locale you initialize the SDK with - because this link has nothing whatsoever to do with the SDK in the first place. When you open the share dialog using FB.ui, you will see that URL of the popup window contains a parameter `locale=…` - but manually changing that still does not get me the dialog in a different language. Could be that Facebook take the language  the current user has specified in their profile as default.

Comment: Yes, confirmed - the `locale` specified in the dialog URL only seems to have an effect if there is no logged-in Facebook user at the time - then the _login mask_ is displayed in whatever I specified via the locale parameter (so f.e. German instead of English.) But after login, the language preference the user has on their profile takes over - the actual share dialog will be displayed in _that_ language, no matter how you initialized the SDK or what locale parameter you specify.

Comment: You are correct. I have checked it now, it depends on user language settings. Thanks!